# How to click cardView clickable false in android?

Tags: android, android-cardview, clickable

Android-developers.blogspot.com API provides  **cardView.setClickble(false)** method to set clickable false, but this method can not be resolved for CardView.

Comment: elaborate please .

Comment: Plase describe your problem in detail. Provide some code for what you are trying to do.

Comment: you have a mistake since according to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html) it has `setClickable`

Comment: CardView is available in android support library. You need to add it to your gradle dependencies and just get reference to pointed card view and do whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: In My application i use multiple cardview and i click any cardview the next activity are open by using intent. After that i click button for this activity and going to previous activity.My problem is that again i want to click same cardview . The cardview doesn't open  but it is still open.  I am using  cardview.setclickable(false) method. this method is not working....

Answer (score 0):

make Cardview object as cardview  then set property

```
Cardview Cardview;
cardView.setClickble(false);
```

make sure you have added dependency in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    // CardView
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.+'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import `CardView`:

```
import android.support.v7.widget.CardView;
```

And instantiate it properly, then call `setClickable`:

```
// Instead of getContext() you might need to use another method.
// Also, if you have the CardView in a xml, use findViewById.
CardView cardView = new CardView(getContext());
cardView.setClickable(false);
```

Comment: This method is not working cardview.setClickable(false); so please sent me another solution.